# Extending TestComplete

Tags: visual-c++, testcomplete

I am extending test complete with new plugins in VC++. Wondering if there is an easy way to debug the errors.

As of now I am building the plugin. Importing it into testcomplete and running it. Is there any other alternative ? Also, Can I generate any log messages from the plugin. Its a tedious task to keep track of the events that occurring internally.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug your plug-in using Visual Studio. To do this, specify TestComplete as a host application for your module.

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide me with some links to go through.

Comment: For example, the official Microsoft documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164704.aspx